# Sending data using protocols

Tags: swift, segue, protocols

I have issues with using protocols to send data back to previous controller. I have studied SO questions and guides, but for some reason my data doesn't get transferred back.

In my second class I create data, that is later being sent back to first class:

```
protocol ImageEditorDelegate {
    func sendImage(image: UIImage, id: String)
}

class PhotoEditorViewController: UIViewController { 

    var delegate: ImageEditorDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  }

@IBAction func didPressSave(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.sendImage(image: finalImage, id: imageThatWasSelected)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

And in my receiving class I have:

```
class NewProductViewController: UIViewController, ImageEditorDelegate { 

    var imageEditor: PhotoEditorViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageEditor?.delegate = self
    }

func sendImage(image: UIImage, id: String) {
        print("Receiving images", image, id)
        switch id {
        case "1":
            selectedImages[1] = image
            productImage1.image = image
        case "2":
            selectedImages[2] = image
            productImage2.image = image
        case "3":
            selectedImages[3] = image
            productImage3.image = image
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing happens, this func never gets called. I think my delegate is nil, or so, but how could I fix this issue? I have Also, I'm using VIPER as architecture with slightly customized segues, may this be the issue? I have tried simple segues, but had same issue.

I understand that this is rather simple question, but I couldn't understand what I doing wrong after I have read articles about protocols.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Prove that `imageEditor` is not `nil` at the time you attempt to set its `delegate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is very wrong. You have two view controllers with property references to one another:

```
class PhotoEditorViewController: UIViewController { 
    var delegate: ImageEditorDelegate?
}
class NewProductViewController: UIViewController, ImageEditorDelegate { 
    var imageEditor: PhotoEditorViewController?
}
```

Those are not `weak` references, so if you ever do get this to work — that is, if you ever arrange things so that the NewProductViewController's `imageEditor` is a PhotoEditorViewController whose `delegate` is that NewProductViewController — you will have a nasty retain cycle and a memory leak.

This suggests that you have not understood the protocol-and-delegate pattern. Only the presented view controller should have a `delegate` property pointing back to the presenter, and it should be `weak`. The presenter does not need any property pointing to the presented view controller, because it presents it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So, I should remove `var imageEditor: PhotoEditorViewController?` and `imageEditor?.delegate = self` from `NewProductViewController`? And make delegate as `weak`. This still didn't solve issue I have. Or I have done something wrong?

Comment: Well, as I said in the comment, you need at some point to have something real you can set the `delegate` of. You are saying `imageEditor?.delegate = self` but how do I know what `imageEditor` is at that moment?

Comment: thank you for your help, I finally managed it to work. And yes, you were right, I didn't understand how it works. Will have to read these articles once again.

Comment: Might help you to download a simple working example. The whole example project is downloadable, but these two files are the ones to look at: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p265presentedViewControllerStoryboard/ch19p601presentedViewController/ViewController.swift https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p265presentedViewControllerStoryboard/ch19p601presentedViewController/SecondViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks. That will me understand it much better

Answer (score 0):

you need to instantiate your photoEditor, like

```
photoEditor =  PhotoEditorViewController()
```

before attempting to set its delegate.

you dont' have to do this next part, but I'd suggest making the delegate variable a weak variable to avoid any retain issues, like so

```
weak var delegate: ImageEditorDelegate?
```

and you'll need to mark the protocol as class like so

```
protocol ImageEditorDelegate : class {
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help. Performed all the actions, but still no luck. Print doesn't get called...